# How to convert Expression<Func<TDomain, bool>> predicate to Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate so that I can pass it to Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, architecture

My project has NLayer architecture.

[image]

My persistence layer is dependent on the domain layer but the domain layer has no knowledge of the entity models.

Similarly my business layer is dependent on the domain layer and has no knowledge of entity models.

While writing the business layer, I apply some predicate logic to filter the data in repository.

But this predicate logic is applied using domain model `Expression<Func<TDomain, bool>>` and Entity Framework works on with `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>`.

How do I convert the predicate?

Is there any workaround to the problem?

Implementation Of Base Repository

```
namespace MyProject.Entity
{
    public abstract class BaseRepository<TId, TDomain, TEntity> : IRepository<TId, TDomain>
    where TId : struct
    where TDomain : class
    where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void Add(TDomain objDomain)
    {
        var entityObj = objDomain.MapTo<TDomain, TEntity>();
         _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entityObj);
        objDomain = entityObj.MapTo<TEntity, TDomain>();
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TDomain> domainObjects)
    {
        var entityObjects = domainObjects.Select(x => x.MapTo<TDomain, TEntity>());
        _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entityObjects).ToList();
        domainObjects = entityObjects.Select(x => x.MapTo<TEntity, TDomain>());
    }

    public void Delete(TId id)
    {
        var objectToRemove = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);

        if (objectToRemove != null)
        { 
            _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Remove(objectToRemove);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TDomain> Find(Expression<Func<TDomain, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
    }

    public TDomain Get(TId id)
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Find(id).MapTo<TEntity,TDomain>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TDomain> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Select(x=>x.MapTo<TEntity,TDomain>()).ToList<TDomain>();
    } 


}
```

}

Comment: Before speaking about predicate, the question is how do you convert `TEntity` to `TDomain`? There is no `DbSet<TDomain>`, so most of the code you posted does not work.

Comment: see the above methods i stuck while working and posted the question i am working on it and i will update it in a while. thanks

Comment: You seem to use AutoMapper. Much of what you want can be achieved by AM's `ProjectTo<>` method as long as the mappings are not too complex. But it's not recommended to use it to map domain objects back to entities, because that usually requires more rules than can sufficiently be configured in AM.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes i am using automapper, Is automapper convert expressions too??

Comment: Ok, then simply use `DbSet<TEntity>().ProjectTo<TDomain>().Where(predicate)`. But note that the predicates must use only EF compatible methods, which breaks the whole abstraction.

Comment: Let me try it out

Comment: @IvanStoev i am using this return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Select(x=>x.MapTo<TEntity,TDomain>()).Where(predicate);

Comment: thats not going to work as EF doesnt understand mapto, you need to use projectto as sugguested

Comment: Yeah you are right it not worked and i had to use projectTo